# How remember target resource url use SAML 2.0 Web Browser SSO Profile?

Tags: saml-2.0

I try to implement SAML 2.0 SP-initiated SSO into my application(my application is Service Provider). Scheme of this process is shown in the image below(from wiki).

[image: SP POST Request; IdP POST Response scheme from wiki]

How I can remember target resource URL (**step 1** on scheme) and later use it on **step 6**? I have only one idea about it: save that URL on server by AuthRequest id on **step 1** and get it by that id on **step 6**. Is that the right way or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relay state parameter can be sent along with the request for SSO service (AuthnRequest). This will be passed back to the SP it the Request Assertion Consumer Service. 
You can use this to store the target URL, similarlyto [how google does it](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation).